# Find invalid image paths in vue project

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, vuejs3, assets

In my Vue 3 project, all images are located in `public/assets/image` then in .vue files I refer to these images like `assets/image/image.png`.

Sometimes I might make a typo in a path or a path might not be correct anymore.

Is there any automated way to find and fix all incorrect paths in a project?

I am using "VS Code" and "IntelliJ IDEA" might be there are any plugins to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

In VS Code there is an extension called **Image preview**
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kisstkondoros.vscode-gutter-preview

If the path is right it shows the image at the left side of the import.

Comment: Looks like this extension doesn't work with relative paths